# Rename files within subfolder and overwrite via batch

Tags: batch-file, overwrite, batch-rename

Here's the current code:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO.
REM rename 
REN "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\folder1\*.*" "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\Folder1\TEST_*.*"

ECHO.
DIR nofile || (PAUSE && EXIT /B 1)
```

I have also tried with move / y

```
move /y "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\folder1\*.*" "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\folder1\TEST_*.*"
```

Both wont work (syntax error or directory not found). Basically trying to rename everything within a sub-folder with a prefix ("Test_") and overwrite any duplicates.

Comment: And when you read the help file for the `REN` command you did not understand this: **Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.**

Comment: Both file name and destination are same "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\Folder1" . Trying to rename all contents within "folder1"

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The syntax in the help file clearly states you cannot specify a path for the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  I have commented the code to help better explain how it works.

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Changes to a directory and saves previous directory to go back to
PUSHD "H:\DIRECTORY with Space\folder1\"

:: Critical that you USE this instead of a normal FOR command.
:: A normal FOR command may attempt to rename a file twice.
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.*') do rename "%%~G" "TEST_%%~G"

:: Goes back to the previous directory.
POPD
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Twisting things a bit. What if I now wanted to remove our prefix and get back to original file name? i.e. now remove "TEST_" from the file name..(dnno if i should create a new question for this?)

Comment: @Wsi, I would start another question for that.  Please at least make an attempt before you post the question and include the code you have been trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

> Welp, seems Squashman has a better answer than me do.
>
> Just to add something for his answer. `(Sorry I can't comment.)`

After `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.*') do ren "%%~G" "TEST_%%~G"`

Adding this can help to rename FOLDER(S) in the directory. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /ad /b *.*') do ren "%%~G" "TEST_%%~G"`

---

But I would suggest to use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /a-d /s /b ^| findstr /v /c:"%~nx0") do (ren "%%a" "TEST_%%~nxa" >nul 2>nul )
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /ad /s /b ^| sort /r') do (ren "%%a" "TEST_%%~nxa" >nul 2>nul )
```

---

And for some more extended functions:

```
@echo off
rem not necessary
title to whom it may rename
color 0a
mode 120,25
goto start
rem is necessary

:start
cls
echo Please enter the path which you want to rename all contents in it with a prefix. No need for the quotes.
echo %%cd%% for the current working directory
set /p p=The path: 
call set p=%p:"=%
echo.
if not exist "%p:"=%" (echo The folder doesn't exist in the typed in path.
echo Current working directory: "%cd%"
echo Please try another path. Press any key to continue.
pause >nul
goto start)
rem adding Squashman's answers here
pushd "%p%"
echo Renaming file(s) in the required folder.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /a-d /s /b ^| findstr /v /c:"%~nx0") do (ren "%%a" "TEST_%%~nxa" >nul 2>nul )
echo Renaming (sub)folder(s) in the required folder.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /ad /s /b ^| sort /r') do (ren "%%a" "TEST_%%~nxa" >nul 2>nul )
echo.
if "%cd%\" == "%~dp0" (echo Do you want to rename this batch too? It will auto exit after renaming.
choice /c yn /n /m "[Y/N] ")
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" (ren "%~nx0" "TEST_%~nx0" >nul 2>nul )
echo Renaming finished. Please press any key to leave the batch.
pause >nul
exit
```